# Jquery inserted all the same selectors after the target div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I don't know how to figure out this, I'm trying to move the button of the `.mainDiv` after each siblings div `.listTwo` and it's inserted correctly, but it inserted all the button after each siblings div `.listTwo`. I need to insert the button only to the current siblings div (`.listTwo`). is it possible to insert the current button after `.listTwo`?

```js
$('.mainDiv').each(function() {

  var button = $(this).children('button');
  var listTwo = $(this).next('ul.listOne').siblings('.listTwo');

  $(button).insertAfter(listTwo);

});
```

```css
.mainDiv {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.listOne,
.listTwo {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">First div of parent main div</div>
  <button class="button">Button1</button>
</div>

<ul class="listOne">
  <li>List one</li>
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listTwo">
  <li>List two</li>
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>


<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">First div of parent main div</div>
  <button class="button">Button2</button>
</div>

<ul class="listOne">
  <li>List one</li>
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listTwo">
  <li>List two</li>
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>


<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">First div of parent main div</div>
  <button class="button">Button3</button>
</div>

<ul class="listOne">
  <li>List one</li>
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listTwo">
  <li>List two</li>
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ikiK I know these Tree Traversal, but now I stuck on it and don't know where is the wrong. Actually I'm working on a project and here I just made this code for the clarity of the question which I'm facing the problem on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this result? just limit `listTwo` it to first one in order after button with `[0]`:

```
$(this).nextAll(".listTwo")[0];
```

```js
$('.mainDiv').each(function() {

  var button = $(this).children('button');
  var listTwo = $(this).nextAll(".listTwo")[0];

  $(button).insertAfter(listTwo);

});
```

```css
.mainDiv {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.listOne,
.listTwo {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">First div of parent main div</div>
  <button class="button">Button1</button>
</div>

<ul class="listOne">
  <li>List one</li>
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listTwo">
  <li>List two</li>
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>


<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">First div of parent main div</div>
  <button class="button">Button2</button>
</div>

<ul class="listOne">
  <li>List one</li>
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listTwo">
  <li>List two</li>
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>


<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">First div of parent main div</div>
  <button class="button">Button3</button>
</div>

<ul class="listOne">
  <li>List one</li>
  <li>List one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listTwo">
  <li>List two</li>
  <li>List two</li>
</ul>
```